# Firebase Crashlytics console not showing crashes

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, xcode10, firebase-console

After following the instructions to integrate Firebase / Crashlytics into an iOS project in Xcode 10.3, I am using Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash() to test, but the crashes are not showing up in the Crashlytics console (I've waited up to 24 hours and see nothing).

I see this in the log

```
[Crashlytics:Crash] report submission successful
```

But nothing shows up in the console.  It does show "I have 50% crash free users", but there is no stack trace and the Crashes show 0 as well.

From my Podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.13.4'
```

From my logs

```
[Crashlytics] Version 3.13.4 (143)
2019-08-29 12:13:08.435079-0500 App[58538:12666639]            

[Crashlytics] Running on iPhone11,8, 12.4.0 (16G77)
2019-08-29 12:13:08.443235-0500 App[58538:12766639]      

[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports:Event] Registered Firebase Analytics event listener

[Fabric] Initialized with kit versions: {
    "com.twitter.answers.ios" = "1.4.1";
    "com.twitter.crashlytics.ios" = "3.13.4";
    "io.fabric.sdk.ios" = "1.10.2";
}
```

In my build phases I have this code:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run
```

and Input Files (I've tried many variations of this path, not sure if it's working correctly):

```
${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist
```

also tried the original instructions path, trying to troubleshoot, but nothing changed.

Also, when I enable debug view, when it crashes I see app_exception come across the stream.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I have some info that might be relevant.  Went through a similar issue with an app that had previously been part of Fabric when it came from Twitter. There's a migration process to go from Fabric to Firebase. In my case, the Fabric credentials were lost and we simply had no way to migrate (even after asking Google for help).  Wound up using MS AppCenter for crash reporting.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any missing dSYMs? That'd usually be the cause of an issue like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a new install.  Just added Firebase Analytics and Crashlytics recently.  The console says I'm up to date on dSYMs, however that could mean there are none since no crashes are showing up in the console

Comment: Your app might need manual activation. Contact support(at)fabric(dot)io with your app’s bundle id / package name and project id.

Comment: Thanks, I have sent them an email.  Waiting to hear back.

Comment: Dear Chris , didi you received any response from fabric support team? I have same issue and I want to know if sending email is the solution

Answer (score 1):

User reached out to Firebase customer support. The issue had to do with illegal characters in the form of whitespace being present in the version name of the app. Removing the white space seemed to restore proper crash reporting on the users Firebase Dashboard.

Comment: Oleg, Please help me as well. I've shared my issue at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63268432/firebase-crashlytics-console-not-showing-crashes-logs-show-implementation-is-co
I think there's a bug with the SDK.