# Old Fabric app won't show crashes on new Firebase implementation

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have implemented Firebase/Crashlytics to an app. I can see in the logs that app is sending crashes. Firebase Console doesn't show anything. I can see crash free user count decreased after the implementation. Console doesn't show up anything. Please help. My app ID: com.obssmobile.mychesspuzzlegame

**I have disconnected the Xcode debugger, relaunched the app and remade the crashes. Issue is persisting.**

Here I can see that crash free users started dropping.
[image: Here I can see that crash free users started dropping.]

Here I can see "report submission successful" log
[image: Here I can see "report submission successful" log]

Console is not updated after several hours.
[image: Console is not updated after several hours.]

Comment: How are you sending crashes to your dashboard? If you're using a virtual device, can you make sure you're disabling Xcodes exception handler by running and crashing your app from the virtual device itself?

Comment: @OlegKodysh I have tried both simulator and real device. I've both tried running crashes while device is connected to the debugger and afterwards. I've relaunched both apps after the crashes. I've tried several different methods for crashes. I've tried crashing when Xcode exception handler and everything else is disconnected and relaunched afterwards. Issue is still ongoing.

Comment: Hmm, ok, could you enable debug mode (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android#enable_debug_logging), and send over a screenshot of the log output?

Comment: It's already in the second picture Oleg, with the debug mode enabled.

Comment: Oh interesting, I was looking for a session ID. Do you see one in your debug log? Also, was this app ever linked to Fabric in anyway?

Comment: @OlegKodysh This is the entire log, no session ID. Yes this app used to use old Fabric implementation from 2017. App owner lost their credentials for Fabric and they can't do migration. Instead we removed entire previous implementation from the app and made the Firebase implementation instead. Does this give any idea about the problem to you?

Comment: Got it. Yep this is an issue that many people have been running into. I'm gonna post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For apps migrated from Fabric that have been deleted and reintegrated with Firebase, sometimes a linking issue in the backend can cause your app to go into a state where the Firebase listener is unable to make the correct settings request to onboard your app using the new SDK. In these situations there are currently two workarounds.

1. Delete your app, and reonboard with either a new bundle ID or using the same bundle ID in a different Firebase Project.
2. Write in to Firebase support and they can try to manually delete the backend link that's causing this issue. However, this should only be done if you have a lot of historical crash data that you need to preserve.

Comment: I have solved the problem by doing something differently while installing the SDK. Thanks for your help as well. I've posted steps I took as an answer.

Comment: Hello @asanli, If we delete the migrated project and using the same bundleID, Do we get a crash that integrated in the fabric previously?